# Which table contains linked media details for lesson?

Tags: php, moodle, moodle-api

I have added a media file in a lesson using `Lesson Settings -> Appearance -> Linked media`. I need to know in which table stores the path of the linked media. I want to get the video URL and pass it to a Webservice for showing it in a mobile application.

Comment: Improve readability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moodle stores the uploaded file details in the table 'mdl_files'. More information is at https://docs.moodle.org/dev/File_API_internals#Files_table